# libspotify Windows 8 RT ARM

Tags: windows-8, spotify

Will there be an ARM version of libspotify released for Windows 8 RT developers?

[Libspotify](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because not about programming as defined in [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment there's no answer to that question. We're aware of the need for one, though, and it's something we're investigating.

Answer (score -2):

I've built despotify on several architectures that lacks official Spotify support (Linux PPC, Linux ARM etc), perhaps that is something that could give you a jumpstart until the proprietary library is released.

Comment: Linux ARM is definitely an officially supported platform, for armv5, v6, and v7. https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/

Comment: It has been for awhile. Are you implying that tomorrow it won't be? :)

Comment: No, I mean that it was a while since I built despotify for Linux ARM -- I think it was one of the first Android releases, and that was a while ago.

Comment: Maybe I'm mixing things up. But Linux PPC still lacks official support though, that was something I played with just a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Ah, ok. :) Yeah, I doubt that Linux PPC will be officially supported, but Win8 RT is a bigger target platform.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19572/discussion-between-nik-reiman-and-christoffer)